construct series of planar polygonal spirals that approximate planar curve
Let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a constant speed spiral, that is
a) $\gamma$ is locally convex w.r.t. 0, that is $\gamma$ has supporting lines that locally lie above $\gamma$ and $\gamma$ locally lies on the boundary of a convex body.
b) $|\gamma|$ is non-decreasing
c) $\angle(\gamma(a),t_\gamma(a))=\frac{\pi}{2}$, where $t_\gamma$ is a tangent vector
d) $|\gamma|$>1
I now need to construct a series of polygons $P^N$, that converge to $\gamma$ w.r.t. to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Furthermore, I require $P^N$ to be a spiral, too.
I have tried approximating $\gamma$ at equidistant $t_n\in[a,b]$, disturbing by small values, and then connecting by linear rays. Also, I tried using local linear approximations by a.e.-existent derivative (follows from constant speed and Rademacher theorem). Both did not get me to the desired series.
Do you have any ideas how to construct the polygonal spirals?
